# How to output the date when the date is pressed? (ttk calendar)

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, calendar

I found a calendar widget that is perfect for my project I am working on. In the code there is a part that should return the date when the day is clicked, but nothing happens.

```
@property
def selection(self):
    """Return a datetime representing the current selected date."""
    if not self._selection:
        return None

year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
return self.datetime(year, month, int(self._selection[0]))
```

I want to be able to, when the user clicks on a date, output the date into another bit of the program ( which I think I can do).
I can post the full code if needed, its playing up with indentation and not displaying correctly.
I also know that it isn't right to copy and paste code from the internet but I have a time limit for my project and we are able do this.
[Calendar with tkinter (print the selected date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535490/calendar-with-tkinter-print-the-selected-date) link to code:)

Comment: That code snippet provides the previously clicked date as an attribute. There is nothing bound to the mouse click.

Comment: how would I got about coding that? thanks for the reply

Comment: The simple solution is to add the code you want to run at the end of the `_pressed` method.

Comment: I really am stuck with this. I understand what you are trying to do, would you be able to post what you think the code looks like? Thanks.